# GC won't collect function in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have done several tests and read a lot about Garbage Collection in Javascript applications but there must be something I'm not getting right.

I have a react app that polls data from a JSON file using fetch every 25 seconds. The function I'm calling is mapped to the props using redux in the App.js. I'm calling the function like this on componentDidMount

```
this.fetchDisplayContent(1000);
```

This is the function's definition which is also located in the App.js

```
fetchDisplayContent = (fetchInterval = 500, repeat = true) => {
    clearTimeout(this._contentInterval);
    this._contentInterval = setTimeout(() => {
        if (this._mode === "preview") {
            this.props.fetchContent(config.WEB_SERVER + '/display/fetchDisplayContents?mode=prvw&localLastUpdate=0&display=' + this._displayId, 0, this._webkey);
        }
        else if (this._mode === "web") { //live web version
            this.props.fetchContent(config.WEB_SERVER + '/display/fetchDisplayContents?mode=web&localLastUpdate=0&display=' + this._displayId, 0, this._webkey);
        }
        else if (this._mode === "module") {
            this.props.fetchModuleContent(config.WEB_SERVER + '/display/fetchModuleContents?mode=prvw&module=' + this._module + '&project=' + this._project + '&module_id=' + this._module_id, this._webkey);
        }
        else { //form offline file
            if (typeof config.DISPLAY === "number") {
                this.props.fetchContent(this._baseURL + '/data/displayContents.json', 0, this._mode);
            } else {
                this.props.fetchContent(this._baseURL + '/data/display_' + this._displayId + '_contents/displayContents.json', 0, this._mode);
            }
        }
        if (repeat) {
            this.fetchDisplayContent();
        }
    }, fetchInterval);
}
```

And this is the action:

```
export function fetchContent(url, lastUpdated, webkey) {
return (dispatch) => {
    let now = new Date();
    let rev = now.getTime()/1000;
    if (url.includes('?')){
        url+="&rev="+rev
    }
    else{
        url+="?rev="+rev
    }
    if (webkey){
        url+="&webkey="+webkey
    }
    fetch(url)
        .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw Error(response.statusText);
            }
            return response;
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((content) => {
            if (Number(content.last_update)>Number(lastUpdated)){
                dispatch(contentFetchSuccess(content))    
            }
            else{
                return null;
            }
        }).catch(() => {
            dispatch(contentHasErrored(true));   
        });
};
```

}

fetchInterval is originally 25000 but I changed it to 500 for testing purposes and reproduce the issue faster.

Here's you can see that references to the handler provided to the setTimeout are not been cleaned out by the GC and the heap keeps growing over time. Eventually the app freezes after a few days and I suspect this is the reason. I confirmed that the number of listeners doesn't increment in the profile as well as the heap's size when the setTimeout is not running.

[Performance Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YQwm.png)

What would be the proper way to call this function in a setTimeout without leaking memory?

Comment: You can see that garbage is collected, otherwise it wouldn't be a sawtooth pattern. If memory usage is growing over days, yes something is leaking memory, but are you certain that it's this timeout?

Comment: @Bergi yes, garbage is being collected but there's some residue that's piling up over time. If I remove the timeout it's a flat line for both heap and listeners. Listener won't stop increasing and the memory profile I take demonstrate that the heap just keeps growing.